# ROS2 - CMake Error - ament_target_dependencies() the first argument must be a valid target name

Tags: ros2, cmake, colcon

I created a plugin ConditionNode to use on the behaviour tree to alter some behavior in navigation. It appears that my cmake file has an error when i run colcon build. The error is: 
Starting >>> goals_and_navigation
Starting >>> lab3_pkg
--- stderr: lab3_pkg
Library Name: lab3_pkg
Dependencies rclcpp;behaviortree_cpp_v3;std_msgs
CMake Error at /opt/ros/humble/share/ament_cmake_target_dependencies/cmake/ament_target_dependencies.cmake:42 (message):
**ament_target_dependencies() the first argument must be a valid target name** 
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:38 (ament_target_dependencies)

### gmake: *** [Makefile:267: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1

Failed   <<< lab3_pkg [0.75s, exited with code 2]
Aborted  <<< goals_and_navigation [0.80s]

Summary: 0 packages finished [1.47s]
1 package failed: lab3_pkg
1 package aborted: goals_and_navigation
1 package had stderr output: lab3_pkg

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(lab3_pkg CXX)
# HELP ME PERES
# NOT ON GITHUB
# if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
#   add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
# endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(behaviortree_cpp_v3 REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)

include_directories(
  include
)

# as in https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_behavior_tree/CMakeLists.txt
set(library_name ${PROJECT_NAME})

# Add your custom node source files NOT IN GITHUB
# set(SOURCES
#   src/DetectCone.cpp
# )

set(dependencies
  rclcpp
  behaviortree_cpp_v3
  std_msgs
)
message("Library Name: ${library_name}")
message("Dependencies ${dependencies}")


ament_target_dependencies(${library_name} # ${library_name}
  ${dependencies}
)

add_library(nav2_my_detection_plugin SHARED src/DetectCone.cpp)

# target_link_libraries(nav2_my_detection_plugin
#   ${dependencies}
# )

list(APPEND plugin_libs nav2_my_detection_plugin)



foreach(bt_plugin ${plugin_libs})
  ament_target_dependencies(${bt_plugin} ${dependencies})
  target_compile_definitions(${bt_plugin} PRIVATE BT_PLUGIN_EXPORT)
endforeach()

# Add an executable target NOT IN GITHUB
# add_executable(DetectCone ${SOURCES})

install(TARGETS ${library_name}
                ${plugin_libs}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
)

install(DIRECTORY include/
  DESTINATION include/
)

# install(DIRECTORY test/utils/
#         DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME}/utils/
# )

# install(FILES nav2_tree_nodes.xml DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME})

# Link the libraries !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
# ament_target_dependencies(DetectCone
#   rclcpp
#   behaviortree_cpp_v3
# )

# Install the executables/libraries !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
# install(TARGETS
#   DetectCone
#   DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
# )

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_export_include_directories(
  include
)

ament_export_libraries(
  ${library_name}
  ${plugin_libs}
)

ament_export_dependencies(${dependencies})

ament_package()
```

Anything else you need me to provide just tell me.
All help is welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Cmake is sequential, you never actually made your library before you try to link it. Switch the order:

```
add_library(${library_name} SHARED src/DetectCone.cpp)

ament_target_dependencies(${library_name} # ${library_name}
  ${dependencies}
)
```

Comment: I had tried this before and didnt work unfortunately it throws the same error. Suposedly i set the library name on this line:
`set(library_name ${PROJECT_NAME})`

Comment: Can you double check. Setting the variable for the name is not the same as creating a target with the name. If not please edit your question to include this fix and the updated error message if you'd like more help.